# How to set morethan max size charecters in NVARCHAR(MAX),sql Server2005

Tags: sql-server-2005

I am using

```
declare @insertsql nvarchar(MAX)

--above @insertsql for sp_executesql takes only nvarchar  as input

set @insertsql='--i am giving More than 10000 characters here -----'

EXEC sp_executesql @insertsql, N'@inXMLRequest XML OUTPUT', @inXMLRequest OUTPUT
```

How do I insert more than 10000 charecters in NVARCHAR(MAX) in sql server 2005?

Comment: How is @insertsql being populated? Through ADO, ADO.NET? And if so, which version?

Comment: Hi Russ Cam, 
Thank u for giving reply, i am using this in stored procedure and @insertsql populating from Dynamic sql
can u help me?

Comment: Where is the value for @insertsql coming from?

Comment: Hi Russ,i am generating that string by dynamically more than 9000 characters.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to All,

Insted of using SP_Executesql directly we Executing nvarchar variable

Above we Are preparing @insertsql nvarchar variable morethan 8000 characters and it is giving to sp_executesql like this

EXEC sp_executesql @insertsql, N'@inXMLRequest XML OUTPUT',@inXMLRequest OUTPUT

insted of above query replaced with below query

Exec ('DeClare @inXMLRequest XML SET @inXMLRequest='------above 8000 characters---')

Finally we will execute that nvarchar string and get out put